# Access violation on c++ graphics library

Tags: c++, sdl, sfml

I'm trying to get a project started which will have a basic Graphical display for representing some data. For it, I was initially going to use SFML as I have already used it and had a lot of success.

However, after repeating the tutorial I've used before in previous projects from 
http://gamecodeschool.com/sfml/building-your-first-sfml-game-project/ to get the basic linkages/compiler settings set up, I'm getting an error on the 
`window.display()`
the line saying it is an access violation. I've scoured the web and looked through all sorts of answers and have double checked to no avail:

1. Using the debug library
2. Using the 32-bit version.
3. Correct Linker Inputs

I gave up and decided to try SDL, however after also following a tutorial to the T where the supplied test code worked which initialized all modules, i tried some basic game loop code (draws a rectangle to the screen) and got another access violation in an almost identical fashion on the `SDL_RenderPresent(renderer)`, aka  same function for rendering in the SDL version as SFML.

I, therefore, think there is some underlying issue that is meaning anytime I try to update the screen my computer is throwing an error. The only thing that has changed since I last used SFML is that I'm now using a monitor connected to my laptop via a dock, but I don't see how that could affect things.

Anyone had any experience with this?

Code of two situations below:

EDIT
SFML:

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

int main()
{
sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(200, 200), "SFML works!");
sf::CircleShape shape(100.f);
shape.setFillColor(sf::Color::Green);

while (window.isOpen())
{
    sf::Event event;
    while (window.pollEvent(event))
    {
        if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
            window.close();
    }

    window.clear();
    window.draw(shape);
    window.display();
}

return 0;}
```

SDL:
Over 150 lines but I have copied it straight from http://headerphile.com/sdl2/sdl2-part-3-drawing-rectangles/
(bottom of the page)

Comment: You should edit the question with complete code snippets for both libraries, so we can be sure the problem is not with your code.

Comment: Just added now below

Comment: Also what's you OS and compiler?

Comment: Using windows 10 and Visual studio 2017 (community)

Comment: What's stacktrace upon this runtime error? Can you check name of SDL rendering backend with `SDL_GetRendererInfo` after renderer creation?

Comment: Appear to have fixed it, see answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after looking into the dll that was causing the issue ig9icd32.dll , It appeared to be an OPENGL component. So I reinstalled the graphics drivers and everything appears to be working!

Comment: Was going to but have to wait two days apparently!